# Cannot add sprites in Ext.draw.Container constructor

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to create an avatar class that can be sized differently when used in different parts of the app. The basic avatar is the following:

```
Ext.define('Avatar', {
    extend: 'Ext.draw.Container',
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    sprites: [{
        type: 'circle',
        fillStyle: '#79BB3F',
        r: 30,
        x: 30,
        y: 30
    }, {
        type: 'text',
        x: 30,
        y: 30,
        text: 'AU',
        textAlign: 'center',
        textBaseline: 'middle',
        fontSize: 30
    }]
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ks4

To be able to make avatars of variable size, I am overriding the constructor and adding the sprites there, where I can then replace the fixed sizes with variables:

```
Ext.define('Avatar', {
    extend: 'Ext.draw.Container',
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    constructor: function() {
        var me = this;
        Ext.apply(me, {
            width: 30, // Changing component size works, ...
            height: 30,
            sprites: [{ // but sprites do not work!
                type: 'circle',
                fillStyle: '#79BB3F',
                r: 30,
                x: 30,
                y: 30
            }, {
                type: 'text',
                x: 30,
                y: 30,
                text: 'AU',
                textAlign: 'center',
                textBaseline: 'middle',
                fontSize: 30
            }]
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kv1

Changing avatar size through the constructor is possible; adding sprites doesn't work. How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the initComponent instead:

```
initComponent: function() {

    var sprites =[{
        type: 'circle',
        fillStyle: '#79BB3F',
        r: 30,
        x: 30,
        y: 30
    }, {
        type: 'text',
        x: 30,
        y: 30,
        text: 'AU',
        textAlign: 'center',
        textBaseline: 'middle',
        fontSize: 30
    }];

   this.setSprites(sprites);

}
```